# How to extract List of all journey only last version with sql

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, query, sql, data-views

My goal is to create a Data Extension with SQL that will contain a report of all Journeys existing in production BU (except for those deleted), but I need the latest version.
I managed to extract all the journey but all the versions are returned to me. In short, I would like 1 record per journey.
I need these fields:
JourneyId
JourneyName (without duplicates, so i need one version,the latest)
JourneyStatus
VersionNumber (the latest)
CreatedDate

are there any suggstions?

Answer (score 0):

At first, we need to identify the group of journey IDs having maximum journey version value.

```SQL
SELECT
      journey.JourneyID
    , MAX(journey.VersionNumber) as VersionNumber
FROM _Journey AS journey
GROUP BY journey.JourneyID
```

Let's call the DE result is "Journey_max_ver_DE"

For other columns, we would need to inner join between the result above and `_Journey` with other columns

```SQL
SELECT
      a.JourneyID
    , a.JourneyName
    , a.VersionNumber
    , a.CreatedDate
    , a.JourneyStatus
FROM _Journey AS a
INNER JOIN
Journey_max_ver_DE as b
ON a.JourneyID = b.JourneyID AND a.VersionNumber = b.VersionNumber
```

To exclude the deleted journeys, just put a condition

```
WHERE a.JourneyStatus != 'Deleted'
```

Combine everything:

```SQL
SELECT
      a.JourneyID
    , a.JourneyName
    , a.VersionNumber
    , a.CreatedDate
    , a.JourneyStatus
FROM _Journey AS a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT
      journey.JourneyID
    , MAX(journey.VersionNumber) as VersionNumber
FROM _Journey AS journey
GROUP BY journey.JourneyID) as b
ON a.JourneyID = b.JourneyID AND a.VersionNumber = b.VersionNumber
WHERE a.JourneyStatus != 'Deleted'
```

Note: I added an additional attribute "JourneyStatus" so we can know the current status of the latest version of the journey.